# Make sshd listen to a specific interface

Tags: linux, ssh, ip, interface

On my machine I'm using OpenVPN which use the tun0 interface. I want sshd to listen only on this interface.

I know, I can specify the IP address to listen to in

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

with a

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

directive. But my IP address will change, so I cannot choose an IP here which is always valid. I know that I can start the daemon only when the VPN is up - that's not the problem.

How can I make sshd only listen on a specific interface (tun0)?

Comment: Firewall off port 22 on any ports that are not `tun0`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that directly as sshd only understands IP addresses. You may be able to knock something together using an openvpn up script

> -up cmd
>                 Shell  command  to run after successful TUN/TAP device open (pre
>                 --user UID change).  The up  script  is  useful  for  specifying
>                 route  commands  which  route  IP  traffic  destined for private
>                 subnets which exist at the other end of the VPN connection  into
>                 the tunnel...

See also the `--down` option to clean up and the relevant parts of the documentation detailing script security etc.

You'll find the IP address of the tun device is passed to the script as an environment variable. Also sshd takes options on the command line of the form

```
-oSomeOption=SomeValue
```

-o option
             Can be used to give options in the format used in the
             configuration file.  This is useful for specifying options for
             which there is no separate command-line flag.  For full details
             of the options, and their values, see sshd_config(5)

So you could use

```
-o ListenAddress=<some address>
```

Presumably you have some out of band method of talking to your VPS so that when this breaks you can contact the server.

Comment: Try: `-o ListenAddress=$(ip addr | awk '/inet/ && /tun0/{sub(/\/.*$/,"",$2); print $2}')`

Comment: @pjz I don't think you need to do that as I'm fairly sure that the IP address of the device is available as an environment variable to the up script. I just don't have the stuff to hand to test it.

Comment: Excellent! The IP is passed to the up script as ifconfig_local=10.xx.xx.xx. A whole bunch of other data (dev_type=tun, common_name=myservername, ifconfig_remote, route_gateway_1, untrusted_ip, ifconfig_local, proto_1, tls_serial_1, tls_serial_0 ...) are passed along.

Comment: Yes I know and now you do too :)

Comment: Maybe you want to edit your answer and add the relevant env variable name? (for future readers)